# How to retrieve a sorted list of objects based on number of incoming relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have an Account object that has a "Incoming" relation with other Account Objects.

I need a couple of cypher queries that retrieve a complete list of accounts sorted by the number of followers each Account.

Query 1:  If, Account One has to 200 followers and Account Two has 100, then Account One will be at the top of the list.  The parameter resultSize will be the size of the top n result.

```
@Query("...")
List<Account> findSortedAccountByFollowers(int resultSize)
```

Query 2: In addition to above, this takes 2 parameters (maxCount and resultSize). It should return only those accounts that have followers less then maxCount e.g. if maxCount is  200 then return those accounts that have followers less 200 sorted by highest to low. Result Size is defined by the parameter resultSize

Here is the Model Class

```
@NodeEntity
public class Account implements Serializable{

   @GraphId
   private Long id;
...
@Fetch
@RelatedTo(type="follows",
      direction= Direction.OUTGOING,
      elementClass = Account.class)
private Set<Account> following = new HashSet<Account>;

   @Fetch
   @RelatedTo(type="follows",
         direction= Direction.INCOMING,
         elementClass = Account.class)
   private Set<Account> followers = new HashSet<Account>;

...

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATED]

1. To implement this:

   ```
   List<Account> findSortedAccountByFollowers(int resultSize)
   ```

   this query should work:

   ```
   MATCH (a:Account)<-[:follows]-(b:Account)
   WITH a, COLLECT(b) AS bs
   ORDER BY SIZE(bs) DESC
   RETURN a
   LIMIT {0};
   ```
2. To implement this:

   ```
   List<Account> findCappedSortedAccountByFollowers(int maxCount, int resultSize)
   ```

   this query should work:

   ```
   MATCH (a:Account)<-[:follows]-(b:Account)
   WITH a, COLLECT(b) AS bs
   WHERE SIZE(bs) <= {0}
   RETURN a
   ORDER BY SIZE(bs) DESC
   LIMIT {1};
   ```

Comment: Forgot that you expect the result to be a collection of `Accounts`. Try my updated answer.

Comment: OK, I see now that you want the relationships in the opposite direction. I have updated my queries accordingly (by just reversing the directionality).

Comment: "maxCount" *should* mean the maximum *allowable* count. So, the behavior you state is what I would expect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124585/discussion-between-cybersam-and-jamie-white).